# A fsm with temporal events

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory

I have defined a finite state machine

```
    Q = {Σ, S, s0, δ, F}

    where 

    Σ = {'[r]equest', '[o]ut', '[i]n', '[e]nd'}

    S = {'[R]eady', '[I]nitiating', '[W]aiting', 'Re[C]eived', 'Re[S]etting'}

    s0 = R,

    F = {R}

    δ =  (q ∈ S and x ∈ Σ)

     q      x      q
    -------------------
     R      r      I
     I      o      W
     W      i      C
     C      e      S
     S      ∈      R
```

However, I have a transition from  W to S via a temporal event†. How should I represent it?
If I add an epsilon-move

```
     W    ∈      S
```

it is not intuitive that it is a temporal event.

†possibly a timeout

Comment: What is a "temporal" event? A timeout?

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at _timed automata_. These are finite automata equipped with clocks; time can pass, clocks can be reset, transitions can be restricted to occur within a given time by clock guards etc.
Here are some nice introductory slides: http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~bouyer/files/bouyer_chennai.pdf

Comment: @DaniCL, Thank you. http://www.cs.aau.dk/~srba/courses/MCS-07/TA.pdf

Comment: @DaniCL: make this an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a comment first, but Suresh asked me to turn it into an answer:

Maybe you want to take a look at *timed automata*. These are finite automata equipped with clocks; time can pass, clocks can be reset, transitions can be restricted to occur within a given time by clock guards etc. Here are some nice introductory slides: [lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~bouyer/files/bouyer_chennai.pdf](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~bouyer/files/bouyer_chennai.pdf)

(This is actually the framework that Vor is using in his answer. His solution makes use of a clock that is reset and a guard for the epsilon transition.)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you must add a clock to the table:

```
 q      x              q
-------------------------
 R      r              I
 I      o              W
 W      i  clock=0     C
 C      e              S
 S      ∈  (clock>T)?  R
```

The S->R (reset) transition can occur only after T "ticks" has elapsed after the receive of [i]nput.

If you want the timeout to start after the [e]nd then you must reset the clock on:

```
 ...
 C      e  clock=0     S
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

On a more abstract level, encode events as symbols in your trace, e.g. `[T]imeout`. As far as I know, this is standard technique when modeling (possibly labeled) transition systems.

This enables you to easily reason about properties your system might have, for instance statements (in temporal logic) like "After any timeout, my machine is in state `S`".

It does not yield a good model for implementations, though.